# C# Drag and Drop - e.Data.GetData using a base class

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop

I am using C# and Winforms 3.5

I have a list of user controls all derived from one base class. These controls can be added to various panels and I'm trying to implement the drag-drop functionality, the problem I'm running in to is on the DragDrop event.

For DragEventArgs `e.Data.GetData(typeof(baseClass))` doesn't work. It wants:

```
e.Data.GetData(typeof(derivedClass1))
e.Data.GetData(typeof(derivedClass2))
etc...
```

Is there a way I can get around this, or a better way to architect it?

Comment: Would having a mutual interface to cast to help?

Comment: No, an interface doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can wrap the data in a common class. For example, assuming your base class is called DragDropBaseControl

```
public class DragDropInfo
{
  public DragDropBaseControl Control { get; private set; }

  public DragDropInfo(DragDropBaseControl control)
  {
    this.Control = control;
  }
}
```

And then the drag drop can be initiated with the following in the base class

```
DoDragDrop(new DragDropInfo(this), DragDropEffects.All);
```

And you can access the data in the drag events using the following

```
e.Data.GetData(typeof(DragDropInfo));
```

Have I understood your requirement correctly?

Comment: I'll give it a try and get back, but it looks promising.

Comment: I would add `e.Data.GetDataPresent` method call to check if that type of data is there before `e.Data.GetData` call.

Answer (score 1):

To get the dragged object dynamically, without even knowing its type or its base type, I use this code inside the `DragDrop` event:

```
baseClass myObject = (baseClass)e.Data.GetData(e.Data.GetFormats()[0]);
```

as `e.Data.GetFormats()[0]` will always hold string representation of the type of the dragged object.

*Note that I assumed there's one object was dragged but the idea is the same for multiple dragged objects.*

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Abdulhameed Shalabi's answer, make sure the object is of the type expected; otherwise an exception will be thrown on the attempt to cast.

One way is a simple try-catch and ignore the drag-drop if the try fails.

```
try {
    baseClass item = (baseClass)e.Data.GetData( e.Data.GetFormats( )[0] );
    if (item != null ) { do stuff }
} catch { }
```