# IDataObject.GetData(string, true) fails if cross assemblies

Tags: c#, types

I am calling IDataObject.GetData() and it is not working for derived classes. I am making the call in one assembly (DLL) and both classes are in a second assembly (DLL). Is there something else that must be done if this is across assemblies?

By not working I mean it returns null. And for GetDataPresent it returns false.

```
bool returnsFalse = dea.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof (ODataBaseNode));
bool returnsTrue = dea.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof (ODataEntitySetNode));
returnsFalse = dea.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof (ODataBaseNode).FullName, true);
returnsTrue = dea.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof (ODataEntitySetNode).FullName, true);

// code in other DLL
public class ODataEntitySetNode : ODataBaseNode
{
```

thanks - dave

Comment: What is the error? Compilation problem? Do you have access to the code? This is just too little info in this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what exactly the type name should be, by inspecting the value of:

```
dea.Data.GetFormats()[0]
```

This should hold the string you need to pass to retrieve the data. My guess is that across assemblies 'something special' needs to be done.

Regarding derived types and `GetDataPresent`, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371437/520044), which proposes a different solution.