# How to pass object through DragandDrop knowing only interface?

Tags: .net, vb.net, drag-and-drop

There are many objects
Implement one interface
How to pass object through DragandDrop knowing only the user interface?

```
Public Class test_1
    Implements I_NAME
    Public Property Name As String Implements I_NAME.Name
End Class

Public Class WPF_TEST

Private Sub txt_drop_source_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseButtonEventArgs) Handles      txt_drop_source.MouseDown
    Dim obj As New test_1
    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(Me, obj, DragDropEffects.All)
End Sub

Private Sub txt_drop_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles txt_drop.DragEnter
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(GetType(I_NAME)) Then
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txt_drop_Drop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles txt_drop.Drop
    Dim obj As Object = e.Data.GetData(GetType(I_NAME))
    If IsNothing(obj) = False Then
        MsgBox(obj.ToString)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You can't use GetDataPresent() here, you don't know the name of the class.  So actually call GetData() and use the *is* operator to see if it implements the interface.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with GetDataPresent to let it accept all the derived types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370697/how-to-deal-with-getdatapresent-to-let-it-accept-all-the-derived-types)