# How can I drag n drop a Generic Object in Winfoms?

Tags: c#, generics, drag-and-drop

I have the following code:

```
private void MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        TileView view = sender as TileView;
        if (view == null) return;
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && _TileHitInfo != null)
        {
            Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;
            Rectangle dragRect = new Rectangle(new Point(_TileHitInfo.HitPoint.X - dragSize.Width / 2,
                _TileHitInfo.HitPoint.Y - dragSize.Height / 2), dragSize);

            if (!dragRect.Contains(new Point(e.X, e.Y)))
            {
                T row = view.GetRow(_TileHitInfo.RowHandle) as T;
                if (row != null)
                {
                    view.GridControl.DoDragDrop(new DragnDropObject<T> {Data =row}, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                }
                _TileHitInfo = null;
                DXMouseEventArgs.GetMouseArgs(e).Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Which appears to set the drag n drop object correctly. However when I go to unbox the object in the recievers DragDrop event handler, the following code does not work (when passed an ImageGrab typed object):

```
if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof (DragnDropObject<ImageGrab>)))
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None;
        }
```

Is there any way to utilize generic types in Drag n Drop object data?

If i define the `T` property in my wrapper object (`DragnDropObject`) to simply `object` and remove the generic type, all seems to work fine.

Is there any way I can keep my generic methods/objects and operate on the types rather than always unboxing my "wrapper object" and then casting the type there?

Comment: Hmm, a generic mouse event handler.  Nobody here can guess what T looks like, use a debugger.  And add e.Data.GetFormats() in your event handler so you can see the actual name of the type.  And consider that if you only accept an ImageGrab object to not call DoDragDrop at all if GetRow() returns something else.  And beware of inheritance, it isn't going to work if ImageGrab is a base class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7371437/17034