# How can I drag and drop classes that implement an interface?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can drag and drop my class onto a UserControl using:

```
private void UcPlot_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
   MyClass myClass = (MyClass)e.Data.GetData(typeof(MyClass));
   Plot( myClass );
}
```

How can I do this with classes that implement an interface?

```
private void UcPlot_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     IPlot myPlot = (IPlot)e.Data.GetData(typeof(IPlot));
     Plot( myPlot );
}
```

These classes may have additional information that isn't needed to plot the data, but is needed elsewhere in the program.

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7371437/17034), use the `as` operator.

Comment: Hans - That worked!  How do I give you credit for solving my problem?